# Problema con Scala y Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala

Tras instalar el plugin de Scala para Eclipse (http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html) y crear mi primer proyecto (un "Hola Mundo") obtuve la siguiente salida  de error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Predef$
    at HolaScala$.main(HolaScala.scala:5)
    at HolaScala.main(HolaScala.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Predef$
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 2 more
```

Realmente, no se como continuar.

Comment: No dices cómo has creado tu proyecto, pero es señal de que no está añadida la librería de Scala. Haz click-derecho en tu proyecto Scala -> Add scala nature. Si no funciona, click derecho en tu proyecto -> Build Path -> Configure Buildpath -> Libraries -> Add Library -> elige la Scala Library (Lo digo de memoria, igual lo pone con otras palabras)

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO.
Inicialmente, instalé Eclipse con el comando`sudo apt install eclipse`, luego, desinstalé esta versión e instalé eclipse desde el archivo .tar.gz. En esta última tarea, me di cuenta de que tenía mal configurada la variable de entorno, así la configuré con mi versión de java (OpenJDK 8), y a partir de ahí, el plugin de Scala funcionó.

Comment: Que bueno que solucioanste tu problema, pero igual puedes probar con intellij comunnity tiene un buen soporte para Scala.